# UIButton subview in UICollectionViewCell not changing control state

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView where each UICollectionViewCell has a UIButton as a subview. The UIButtons respond to taps no problem (their targets get fired), but the button itself does not change to the selected state (no change in look and feel of the button). I have a hunch it's because of the UICollectionViewCell not properly forwarding its touch events to the button, but I'm not sure. Even if that's so, how do I set things up so that the button's state changes properly in this scenario?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `UIScrollview` (and thus `UICollectionView` too) has a property called `delaysContentTouches`, by default it is set to *YES*, change this to *NO* and your button should highlight like it is supposed to.

Comment: Beautiful! Worked perfectly. For the curious, here's the relevant documentation on that property: `A Boolean value that determines whether the scroll view delays the handling of touch-down gestures.
If the value of this property is YES, the scroll view delays handling the touch-down gesture until it can determine if scrolling is the intent. If the value is NO , the scroll view immediately calls touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:. The default value is YES.`

Answer (score 0):

If i may suggest an alternative, the UICollectionView has an awesome delegate method called

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { }
```

which could handle the click to that cell... if you are looking for specific events to happen like seeing an image change to the state of the button, you could hard code that in... when they press the button do one thing, when they release the button do another thing....

according to the documentation as well

UIControlStateSelected
Selected state of a control. For many controls, this state has no effect on behavior or appearance. But other subclasses (for example, the UISegmentedControl class) may have different appearance depending on their selected state. You can retrieve and set this value through the selected property.

in laymens terms.. for a UIButton the "Selected State" does nothing...

if the the button is suppose to dim when it's clicked and it's not doing that, then you may have to do that programmatically if, but i'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do...

the dimming feature is with in the highlighted state

UIControlStateHighlighted
Highlighted state of a control. A control enters this state when a touch enters and exits during tracking and when there is a touch up event. You can retrieve and set this value through the highlighted property.

in laymens terms, you touch the button it's highlighted

to see if the button is changing states properly you can do something like this

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(functionToCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];

NSLog(@"Selected: %i", button.selected);
NSLog(@"Highlighted: %i", button.highlighted);
NSLog(@"Normal State or not: %i", button.state);
```

the "functionToCall will be called when any type of touch even happens to the button and with in that function you could have those 3 NSLogs which will print to your console the different UIControlState values, this will show that the button is working properly and show that it may be a UIViewCollection error, if it's the UICollectionView... then you will have to programmatically dim the button :3

hope this helps !

Comment: I tried setting the button programmatically to the highlighted state, but it still didn't work.